# save arrays of json in firebase with my swift 4 app

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase

I have an app that shows 4 options. Everyday you click on one or more of the options. Right now, it's storing in the firebase database like an array of string, where every string is one of the options. Like this

```
  override func addSelection(selection: String) {
self.quitPlan.medications.append(selection)
    }


    var medications: [String] {
        get {
            return document[Properties.medications.rawValue] as? [String] ?? []
        }

        set {
            document[Properties.medications.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }
```

But I actually want an array of jsons, with the option and the option. I have try:

```
  override func addSelection(selection: String) {

        let medicationSelected = Medication(medication: selection, date: Date())
        self.quitPlan.medications.append(medicationSelected)

    }


    var medications: [Medication] {
        get {
            return document[Properties.medications.rawValue] as? [Medication] ?? []
        }

        set {
            document[Properties.medications.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }


struct Medication {

    let medication: String
    let date: Date
}
```

But it's not working, I'm getting `'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __SwiftValue'`

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using the Firebase Real Time Database or Firestore? Also, none of the code in your question saves or loads anything from Firebase so it would be helpful to know what that looks like. Lastly, including a snippet of your intended structure will help us understand what you're expecting your database to look like. Oh, and as @vadian mentions in his answer, you cannot store self created Structures or Classes in Firebase - what can be stored is dependent on which Firebase product you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
struct Medication {

let medication: String
let date: Date

private let divider = "|"

func toString() -> String {
    return midication + divider + date.toString()
}

func from(_ string: String) -> Medication {
    let arr = string.split(divider)
    let medication = arr[0]
    let date = // TODO: Date from string arr[1]
    return Medication(medication: medication, date: date)
}}
```

and

```
self.quitPlan.medications.append(medicationSelected.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase cannot save custom Swift structs.

A possible solution is to encode the array of `Medication` to a JSON string.

```
struct Medication : Codable {
    let medication: String
    let date: Date
}
```

In the database change the type from an array of string to single string

```
var medications: [Medication] {
    get {
        guard let medicationJSON = document[Properties.medications.rawValue] as? String,
           let data = medicationJSON.data(using: .utf8),
           let medi = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Medication].self, from: data) else { return [] }
        return medi
    }

    set {
        let medicationData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        document[Properties.medications.rawValue] = String(data: medicationData, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore can save a Swift struct to a collection, there is a module for this.

First, you should include the module:

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
```

Then, just do:

```
db.collection("yourCollectionName").document(from: yourSwiftObject)
```

It will be converted to be saved in your Firestore collection.